# Thread not releasing memory

Tags: java, multithreading, audio, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

> I'm trying to play a sound effect in my program using threads, I searched the web and as I understand when a thread reaches the end of the run function it will become free for the GC to collect.
>
> However when I call for the function many times one after another the task manager shows a high increase at memory usage and it never went back down, I waited for 2 minutes for the GC but there was no effect.

Here is the code that I use for playing sound effect:

```
public static void playSfx(final String path) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path));

                final int BUFFER_SIZE = 128000;
                SourceDataLine sourceLine = null;

                AudioFormat audioFormat = audioInputStream.getFormat();
                DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);

                sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
                sourceLine.open(audioFormat);

                if (sourceLine == null)
                    return;

                sourceLine.start();
                int nBytesRead = 0;
                byte[] abData = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                while (nBytesRead != -1) {
                    try {
                        nBytesRead = audioInputStream.read(abData, 0, abData.length);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (nBytesRead >= 0) {
                        sourceLine.write(abData, 0, nBytesRead);
                    }
                }

                sourceLine.drain();
                sourceLine.close();
                audioInputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

What should I do to reclaim the lost memory?

Comment: What makes you think that the memory is *lost*? You don’t use it so it doesn’t matter whether it looks like allocated or free. So both, the JVM and your operation system, do not urge to free memory unless you *need* it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this. For me this will peak at about 60k memory usage, which
considering the language in question is perfectly ok imo. Do you have any small
code which reliably reproduces the problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        playSfx("somesortsound.wav");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

In addition, what are your expectations when it comes to memory usage? Predicting GC
behaviour is not easy, and you are not guaranteed to see memory freed just because
you wait a while. Especially so if you are not allocating a lot.

I would also get rid of the `try catch` in your read loop. You don't handle any
exception there anyway, and you catch it outside of the loop as well. If the
stream causes an IO exception chances are you want to abort the loop anyway, right?

Answer (score 0):

Running that method from the following class with compatible files and without any exceptions; I did not see that behaviour.

```
public class PlaySound {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String filePath = "C:"+File.separator+"bach.wav"; 
    playSfx(filePath);
    playSfx(filePath);
    playSfx(filePath);
    while(true){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
}
```

It could be a memory leak. You are not managing the resources with a finally block (or 'try-with-resources'), coupling this with return statements could result in the internals of the AudioInputStream driver maintaining a reference to the file.

I would use a try-with-resources block.

```
 try(AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(path));){
   //your code
}
```

Also, I wouldn't use the task manager to reliably determine the garbage collectors behaviour, there are many components that determine the size of a Java process in memory.

To gain an understanding of what's going on; use VisualVM. (This is located in the bin directory of your jdk). You can see when the garbage collector is active, as well as the size of the heap compared to its current maximum size. You can also 'Request' (does not guarantee) garbage collection, which will give you an indication of the amount of memory required for 'survivors', and the amount that can be freed.

Admittedly 2 minutes is a long time, but it is worth mentioning garbage collection usually occurs as a failure to allocate memory to a particular generation, but this is dependant on the particular GC algorithm being used. In other words, if it didn't reach an upper limit then it is possible it wouldn't have performed a garbage collection.

[This article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/memorymanagement-whitepaper-150215.pdf) is potentially worth a read/glance; it details various different garbage collectors and how they are expected to function.